# This number sequence works but is it correct?

Tags: powershell

I needed to add an virtual HDD to several VMs so I ended up using this to do it:

```
get-vm server[2..3..6][1-3].domain.com | new-harddisk -CapacityGB 10
```

This added a 10gig HDD to server:

```
server21.domain.com
server22.domain.com
server23.domain.com

server31.domain.com
server32.domain.com
server33.domain.com

server61.domain.com   
server62.domain.com
server63.domain.com
```

That is what I wanted... but is the syntax I used correct? I know that 1..3 would normally expand to 1 2 3 but in this case it does not which is why i used 1-3 in the second part and 2..3..6 ended up only doing 2 3 6.

Can somebody please verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1..3` is PowerShell array syntax to generate an array, but in the context of `Get-VM xyz[1..3]` it's not. You can see from the colouring in the PowerShell ISE:

[image: Examples of how it's being parsed showing ISE syntax highlighting]

You can also see it if you run it through the parser and see how it's being read:

```
{get-vm server[1..3..5]}.Ast.FindAll({$true}, $true)

# includes output

StringConstantType : BareWord
Value              : server[1..3..5]
StaticType         : System.String
```

vs.

```
{get-vm $server[1..3..5]}.Ast.FindAll({$true}, $true)

Operator      : DotDot
Left          : 1
Right         : 3

Value      : 1
StaticType : System.Int32

Value      : 3
StaticType : System.Int32

Value      : 5
StaticType : System.Int32
```

In other words, your syntax is wrong for PowerShell array expansions (they can't be chained together), but these aren't PowerShell array literals, they're literal strings passed as parameters to the Get-VM cmdlet, which is (presumably) treating them as wildcards in some way.

[Hyper-V `Get-VM`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848479.aspx?) says it doesn't support wildcard characters.

[VMware `Get-VM`](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FGet-VM.html) does have wildcards demonstrated in its examples.

From a bit of playing around with PowerCLI, it looks like the `..` are being ignored, and `[236]` means "*2, 3 or 6 in this position*" and `[1-3]` means "*a digit between 1 and 3 in this position*"`. Which is getting the output you want, so in that sense, the syntax is fine. And probably easier than if you had been able to use PS arrays.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I am using PowerCLI and [236] behaves as you have explained... interesting that it does not work in Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not correct (if you try you probably receive an error). You could create two sequences (1, 2, 3) and (2, 3, 6) and iterate over both to create your desired 9 combinations. However, I would just do it like this:

```
21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 61, 62, 63 | ForEach-Object { 
    get-vm ('server{0}.domain.com' -f $_) | 
        new-harddisk -CapacityGB 10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your number set is a little larger than just a handful, I can see value in some sort of algorithm to do this.

For something really thrown together in haste, you could use:

```
2,3,6 | % {$x=$_; 1..3 | % {"server$($x*10+$_).domain.com"}}
```

And then pipe that into whatever you wanted to do with the entries...